# Reason of band inversion in graphene in kane and mele model

Tags: condensed-matter

I am trying to simulate the graphene zigzag nano ribbon model of kane and mele.
But I dont know how the inversion of band is taking place in it.Can anyone please suggest me about this .What makes this inversion of bands to happen in general? How should my hamiltonian look like in order to have the cross over of bands?I am making it using 4x4 matrix where pseudospins for sublattices and spin orbit coupling are considered,that is what makes my hamiltonian a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: If you tune the spin-orbit coupling parameter, you should see the gap close and re-open. That should give you an indication as to whether your bands have been inverted.